Construct $(a_n)$ such that $\sum_n a_n^k$ converges for only specified $k$
Let $A$ be a (not necessarily finite) collection of odd natural numbers, for example $A = \{1,5,7,19\}$. I want to find a sequence $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb R$ (or prove existence of such sequence) such that for any $k \in \mathbb N$, the series $\sum_n a_n^k$ converges if and only if $k \in A$.
My attempt was the sequence in the form $$ \frac{b_1}{\log 2}, \frac{b_2}{\log 2}, \cdots, \frac{b_r}{\log 2}, \frac{b_1}{\log 3}, \cdots, \frac{b_r}{\log 3}, \frac{b_1}{\log 4}, \cdots, \frac{b_r}{\log 4} ,\cdots $$
and $b_i$'s are to be determined such that $b_1^k + b_2^k + \cdots + b_r^k = 0$ if $k \in A$ and $b_1^k + b_2^k + \cdots + b_r^k \ne 0$ if $k\not\in A$.
If we can find such $(b_i)$ then it is done because $\sum_n \frac{1}{(\log n)^k}$ is divergent for all $k$. However I found out that it is not easy even in the simplest nontrivial case $A = \{1,3\}$.
How can I construct such a sequence? Would it require some form of AoC?
Thank you for any form of hint, help, or solution.

My guess would be that the only possible answer is $A= 2\mathbb{N}+ k$ where $k$ is odd, I’m trying to prove it now

With complex coefficient you could have more convenient spacings

The sequence cannot be of eventually positive numbers or absolutely convergent, and you can use the comparison test to verify that if $\sum |a_n|^k$ converges, then for any $K\geq k$ you will eventually have $|a_n|^K\leq |a_n|^k$, so convergence of $\sum |a_n|^k$ will imply convergence of $\sum |a_n|^K$, even if $K$ is not in $A$.

@AdamRubinson your solution for $1$ is false

I tried Abel’s summation but in the end something blocks. I would need $a_n^2$ to be decreasing up to a certain rank (or a default that is the general term of an alsolutely convergent series)

Quick question, was it a part of an assignment or do you wonder if if was true?

@julio_es_sui_glace It was a part of exam past paper, and the question says "prove it" so I think it is true. But not being able to solve it

I put you the proof for the case where A is infinite

Also it is my personal opinion that this question without further indications is really hard to do during the duration of the exam

This is a ridiculous question to ask in an exam.

If you like it, I have proven a generalization for any $A$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5003195/construction-of-lefta-n-right-n-in-mathbb-n-in-mathbbc-mathbbn

I will deal with the case $|A| = \infty$ with a lot of inspiration from Robert Israel's answer.
The idea of the proof is from the mechanic used by the Cantor’s diagonal extraction process.
Take $A= \{n_1 < n_2 < \dots\}$ an infinite set of odd natural numbers, we will construct with a procedure inspired by cantor's diagonal extraction process, a suitable sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$\sum a_n^k \, \text{ converges} \iff k \in A$$
But this time we will modify it just a bit (or maybe more than I thought when I began writing this).

First step
Let $m \geq 1$, we define $A_m = \{n_1,\dots,n_m\}$ and the polynomial
$$g_m(X) = \left(\prod_{j=1}^m (X-2^{n_j}) \right)^2 = \epsilon_{2m}d_{2m}X^{2m} + \epsilon_{2m-1}d_{m-1}X^{m-1} + \cdots + \epsilon_1 d_1 X+ \epsilon_0 d_0$$
with $\epsilon_i \in \{-1,1\}$ and $d_i \in \mathbb{N}$.
We then define
$$f_m(x) = g_m(2^x) = \left( \prod_{j=1}^m (2^x-2^{n_j}) \right)^2$$
and
$$\forall 0\le i \le 2m, \quad \forall 1\le j \le d_i, \qquad b_{D_i + j} = \epsilon_i 2^i \qquad \text{where} \, D_i = \sum_{l =0}^{i-1} d_l.$$

A few remarks:

$\epsilon_{2m}=1$, $d_{2m}=1$, $\epsilon_0 = (-1)^m$ and $d_0 = 2^{n_1 + \cdots + n_m}$.
I have squared the function Robert uses for positivity since the size of my paquets changes (it may not be necessary but I did not want to make things more complicated than they already are).
$r_m = D_{2m+1}$.


Just as in Robert's solution. Now we make some observations:

$f_m(k) = 0 \iff k \in A_m$.
$f_m(k) \in \mathbb{N}$.
$f_m(k) = b_{m,1}^k + \cdots + b_{m,r_m}^k$ for odd $k$.


Second step: construction of the sequence.
Since the summation by paquets will be more tricky than usual, we need to define not $1$ but $4$ sequences for more coherence: $s_n$, $c_n$, $R_n$ and $a_n$. We could do it "by hand" but since it begins to be very tricky, let us do it right!

Initialisation:
$$\begin{align*}
s_1 &= 2\\
c_1 &= 1\\
R_1 &= 0\\
a_j &= \frac{b_{1,j}}{\log 2} & \text{for} \quad 1\le j \le r_1 
\end{align*}$$
If $\dfrac{\sum_j |b_{(c_{n-1}+1),j}|^{n_{(c_{n-1}+1)}}}{\log (s_{n-1}+1)} \le \frac{1}{n}$
$$\begin{align*}
s_n &= s_{n-1} + 1 \\
c_n &=c_{n-1}+1\\
R_n &= R_{n-1} + r_{c_{n-1}}\\
a_{R_n+j} &= \frac{b_{c_n,j}}{\log s_n} & \text{for} \quad 1\le j \le r_{c_n} 
\end{align*}$$
If $\dfrac{\sum_j |b_{(c_{n-1}+1),j}|^{n_{(c_{n-1}+1)}}}{\log (s_{n-1}+1)} > \frac{1}{n}$
$$\begin{align*}
s_n &= s_{n-1} + 1 \\
c_n &=c_{n-1}\\
R_n &= R_{n-1} + r_{c_{n-1}}\\
a_{R_n+j} &= \frac{b_{c_n,j}}{\log s_n} & \text{for} \quad 1\le j \le r_{c_n} 
\end{align*}$$


The intuition behind this, is that I need to ensure that the divisor is big enough compared to the paquet to converge to $0$ otherwise we don't have convergence for $k \in A$ since the paquet will be too big. In this spirit we have:

$s_n$ that knows the number of the paquet we are in.
$c_n$ that knows the index $m$ of $A_m$ the paquet recognizes and ensure that the divisor is big enough for the sum of his paquet to absolutely converge to $0$.
One can say that if $c_n = m$, all the $k \in A$ smaller or equal to $n_m$ (so the $m$ first) are dealt with.
$R_n$ that just counts the beginning index of each paquet: the $n$-th paquet is $\{R_n +1, R_n + 2, \dots, R_{n+1}\}$.



Last step: proof of convergence (and divergence).
Now if we take $N = R_p + q $ big enough for the considerations we need further with $1 \le q \le r_{c_p}$ (so $N$ in the $p^\text{th}$ paquet).
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^k 
&= \sum_{t=1}^{p-1} \sum_{j=1}^{r_{c_t}} a_{R_t +j }^k  
+ \sum_{j=1}^q a_{R_p + j}^k\\
&= \sum_{t=1}^{p-1} \sum_{j=1}^{r_{c_t}} \left( \dfrac{b_{c_t,j}}{\log s_t}  \right)^k 
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \\
\end{align*}$$
Case 1: $k$ is odd.
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^k 
&= \sum_{t=1}^{p-1} \sum_{j=1}^{r_{c_t}} \left( \dfrac{b_{c_t,j}}{\log s_t}  \right)^k 
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \\
&= \sum_{t=1}^{p-1}   \dfrac{f_{c_t}(k)}{\log (s_t)^k}
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \\
\end{align*}$$
Case 1.1: $k \in A$
There exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_m = k$, thus for $m' \ge m, \, f_{m'} (k) = 0$.
We take $T$ such that $c_T = m$:

Note that it exists since $c_n$ is non-decreasing and non-stationary, thus it diverges to $\infty$.

We define $\alpha(t)$ as the unique integer verifying
$$c_{\alpha(t)} = c_t$$
And
$$c_{\alpha(t)} = c_{\alpha(t)-1} +1$$

it is easy to verify that it is increasing and non stationary thus it diverges to $\infty$.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^k 
&= \sum_{t=1}^{p-1}   \dfrac{f_{c_t}(k)}{\log (s_t)^k}
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \\
&= \sum_{t=1}^{T-1}   \dfrac{f_{c_t}(k)}{\log (s_t)^k}
+ \sum_{t=T}^{p-1}   \dfrac{f_{c_t}(k)}{\log (s_t)^k}
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \\
&= \sum_{t=1}^{T-1}   \dfrac{f_{c_t}(k)}{\log  (s_t)^k}
+ 0
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \\
&= \sum_{t=1}^{T-1}   \dfrac{f_{c_t}(k)}{\log (s_t)^k}
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k
\end{align*}$$
But the first term is a constant, so we only need to study the second (recall that $|b_{c_p,j}|\ge 1$ so $|b_{c_p,j}|^k\le |b_{c_p,j}|^{n_{c_p}}$:
$$\begin{align*}
\left| 
\sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k
\right|
&\le \sum_{j=1}^q  \dfrac{|b_{c_p,j}|^k}{\log (s_p)^k} \\
&\le \sum_{j=1}^{r_{c_p}} \dfrac{|b_{c_p,j}|^{n_{c_p}}}{\log( s_p)} \\
&\le \sum_{j=1}^{r_{c_{\alpha(p)}}}  \dfrac{ |b_{c_{\alpha(p)},j}|^{n_{c_{\alpha(p)} } } }{\log( s_{\alpha(p)})} \\
&\le \dfrac{1}{\alpha(p)} \to 0 
\end{align*}$$

We have $\log (s_p)^k \ge \log s_p$ since we supposed $N$ big enough.

Which means $\sum a_n^k$ converges!
Case 1.2: $k \notin A$.
We have from the previous observation $f_m(k)\ge 1$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$. This gives us
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^k 
&= \sum_{t=1}^{p-1}   \dfrac{f_{c_t}(k)}{\log (s_t)^k}
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \\
&\ge \sum_{t=1}^{p-1}   \dfrac{1}{\log (s_t)^k}
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \\
&\ge \sum_{t=1}^{p-1}   \dfrac{1}{\log (s_t)^k}
- \left|\sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \right|\\
&\ge \sum_{t=1}^{p-1}   \dfrac{1}{\log (s_t)^k}
- \dfrac{1}{\alpha(p)} \to \infty\\
\end{align*}$$
Which means $\sum a_n^k$ diverges.
Case 2: $k$ is even.
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^k 
&= \sum_{t=1}^{p-1} \sum_{j=1}^{r_{c_t}} \left( \dfrac{b_{c_t,j}}{\log s_t}  \right)^k 
+ \sum_{j=1}^q \left( \dfrac{b_{c_p,j}}{\log s_p}  \right)^k \\
&\ge \sum_{t=1}^{p-1} \sum_{j=1}^{r_{c_t}} \dfrac{1}{\log (s_t)^k} \\
&\ge \sum_{t=1}^{p-1} \dfrac{r_{c_t}}{\log (s_t)^k} \\
&\ge \sum_{t=1}^{p-1}   \dfrac{1}{\log (s_t)^k}  \to \infty\\
\end{align*}$$
Which means $\sum a_n^k$ diverges.

Conclusion:
As wished,
$$\sum a_n^k \, \text{converges} \iff k \in A.$$
In summary, as counterintuitive as in can be, for any subset $A \subset 2 \mathbb{N} +1$ (it can even be empty of course) there exists an explicit (so no need of the AoC) real sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\sum a_n^k$ converges iff $k \in A$.

I tried to make it comprehensible  but it was not easy! Here $n_{c_n}$ is the $c_n$-th element of A  and in particular $f_{c_n}$ detects elements of $A_{c_n}$ don’t hesitate to ask wher you don’t get it or if you think there is a typo or an error

@mathhello I had some minor error fixed: when I make the case disjunction for the sequences construction I modified just a bit the conditions, and I also horribly wrote $\log (s_t)^k = \log (ks_t)$ which I have obviously fixed (but it does not change the reasoning).

Now, at last, I think I understood your proof(Took me whole day!). I have one question: at the last part, how can you guarantee that $\sum_{j=1}^{r_{c_p}} \frac{|b_{c_p,j}|^{n_{c_p}}}{\log s_p} \leq \frac{1}{p}$? Because in the definition $c_p$, such inequality seems to be true for some $p$, not all $p \in \mathbb N$.

@mathhello CYou are right, there is a small adaptation that needs to be made, I’ll correct it

@mathhello It should be fixed

If $A = \{n_1, \ldots, n_m\}$ is finite, let $f(k) = \prod_{i=1}^m (2^{k} - 2^{n_i})$.  The only solutions to $f(k) = 0$ are $A$.  Expand $f(k)$ as
a sum of terms $\pm 2^{jk}$.  Corresponding to these take $\pm 2^j$.
For example, with $A = \{1,3\}$, $$f(k) = (2^k - 2)(2^k - 8) = 2^{2k} - 10 \cdot 2^k + 16 = 1 + \ldots + 1 - 2^k - \ldots - 2^k + 2^{2k}$$
with $16$ $1$'s and $10$ $-2^k$'s.  Thus if $b_1, \ldots, b_{27}$ is a sequence consisting of
$16$ $1$'s, $10$ $-2$'s and one $4$, let the sequence $a_i$ consist of
$b_1/\log(2), \ldots, b_{27}/\log(2), b_1/\log(3),\ldots, b_{27}/\log(3), \ldots$.

From this you can probably deduce a method for infinite A using a similar argument to cantor diagonal extraction no?
